# How to list all months that have a requirement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have 3 tables:

```
Student (
    student_id, 
    student_type_id, 
    start_date, 
    end_date
) 

RequiredAssignments (
    student_type_id, 
    monthly_assignments_required
)

Assignment (
    student_id, 
    datecompleted
)
```

Basically, in the `RequiredAssignments` table, the `monthly_assignments_required` field is an integer that states how many assignments each student of a given type must turn in each month.

I want to build query that lists a student, a month, how many assignments are required and how many they turned in for every student, for every month between each students given start and end dates.

I'm stuck right now at getting the `student_id` listed with each month between start and end dates (inclusive)...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the "monthly_assignments_required" the same for each month?? To me, it seems like you're missing a "month" or something like that on your RequiredAssignments table...... or how do you know how many assignments each student type has for a given month??

Comment: It's always the same...students of type 1 will always have to turn in 4 assignments monthly, type 2 will always turn in 3 monthly and so on and so forth.

Comment: Can you show us what your query looks like so far?

Comment: Do you want the months as columns like a cross-tab, or do you want a row-list? Former works only with single-student query.

Comment: Definitely a row list, this eventually will have to generate an SSRS report, and a cross-tab won't be of much use there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a numbers table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers
(
n INT PRIMARY KEY
);


WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),   --2
        E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b), --4
        E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b), --16
        E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b), --256
        E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b)  --65,536
INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
FROM E16
```

Once you have this you can do something like (untested)

```
SELECT s.student_id,
       DATEADD(MONTH,n-1,start_date) AS MonthStart,
       COUNT(*) 
FROM Student s
JOIN dbo.Numbers ON n <= (1 + DATEDIFF(MONTH,s.start_date, s.end_date)) 
LEFT JOIN Assignment a ON a.student_id = s.student_id and a.datecompleted >= DATEADD(MONTH,n-1,start_date) and a.datecompleted < DATEADD(MONTH,n,start_date)
GROUP BY s.student_id, DATEADD(MONTH,n-1,start_date)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is sort of the route I've been going. I'll post what I come up with once it's done, but this will certainly help!